# Android Fragment from Layout - Retain variable data

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I've been searching for hours and tried numerous methods but cannot seem to grasp my head around the idea / figure out how to retain/restore data in a ViewPager Fragment when it is destroyed and then recreated.

Here is what I have -

An **activity** where I setup the ViewPager and PageAdapter

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view_pager);

    //Setup pager and adapter
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
}
```

My **PageAdapter** where I setup a fragment with a bundle using .newInstance()

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    ScreenSlidePageFragment fragment = new ScreenSlidePageFragment();
    return fragment.newInstance(position);
}
```

My **Fragment** that has a layout that includes a TextView that shows the user a question, a picture, and two True/False buttons. New instance is returned back to the Adapter.

```
public static ScreenSlidePageFragment newInstance(int position) {
    ScreenSlidePageFragment fragment = new ScreenSlidePageFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("page_position", position + 1);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

//the fragment is newly created for the first time or recreated when exiting the view
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, parent, false);

    //Handle a question being displayed on each fragment
    count = getArguments().getInt("page_position") - 1;
    mQuestionText = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.questionText);
    mQuestionText.setText(bank.get(count).getQuestion());

    //change the image depending on correct / incorrect answer
    mPhoto = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    trueButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.true_button);
    falseButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.false_button);

    //True Button is pressed
    trueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(bank.get(count).getAnswer()) {
                mPhoto.setImageResource(R.drawable.right);
                clickable = false;
            }
            else {
                mPhoto.setImageResource(R.drawable.wrong);
                clickable = false;
            }
            trueButton.setClickable(clickable);
            falseButton.setClickable(clickable);
        }
    });
```

What I cannot figure out for the life of me, is how to retain/save that fact that the user has pressed a button and which picture to display when the fragment is restored. I have tried a number of options using onResume(),  getArguments(), onSaveInstanceState(), onActivityCreated() etc but none of them seem to work.

I can fix the problem by keeping all my ViewPager pages alive using setOffscreenPageLimit(total pages) but have read this is a bad idea since it takes up a large amount of memory.

Comment: Why do you add 1 when you set args and subtract 1 when you get args?

Comment: No reason at all I removed the +1 and -1. I was messing with the first fragment in the sequence a while ago and must of added +1 to fix the out of range error without realizing I still had the -1. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Do you have code for ScreenSlidePagerAdapter.java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example that I use that can help you where an ArrayList of urls for pictures is saved for later when the view is recreated, you need to override onSavedInstanceState and save your variables in a bundle, then retrieve the values from the bundle when the view is created again, hope this can help

```
ArrayList<String> picutersUrl = new ArrayList<String>();

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if(savedInstanceState!=null)
        {
          picutersUrl = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList("My Pictures");
        }


      @Override
      protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle) 
      {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(bundle);
        bundle.putStringArrayList("My Pictures", picutersUrl   );
      }
```

Comment: This does work, I played with it a while ago and swore it didn't. Android Studio was acting up also and wouldn't give me logs to view the source of my problem. Thanks for posting it, trying it again really helped me out! I was going bonkers trying to figure out what was wrong and it turned out the Bundle Code was working as expected all along I was just triggering the change in the wrong area.

Answer (score 0):

I too have used PagerAdapter to support few static tab widgets. I think you need to add code to ScreenSlidePagerAdapter. Google webpage at [PagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html).
Note and read the details on override method **instantiateItem**. This is where you populate the UI.
Code example for ScreenSlidePagerAdapterfrom (PagerAdapter subclass), using your posted code:

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, parent, false);
...
    trueButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.true_button);
}
```

In reality with Views in this framework, you're responsible on saving the state of UI elements. In my ListView, I am caching and saving up to 100 rows of data and refreshes it in an Adapter, for example. For caching, I created custom class containing the UI data.